# Problem with operator ==

Tags: c++, operators, equals-operator

I am facing some problem with use of operator == in the following c++ program.

```
#include < iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(char *b)
        {
            a = b;
        }
        A(A &c)
        {
            a = c.a;
        }
        bool operator ==(A &other)
        {
            return strcmp(a, other.a);
        }
    private:
        char *a;
};


int main()
{
    A obj("test");
    A obj1("test1");

    if(obj1 == A("test1"))
    {
        cout<<"This is true"<<endl;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with `if(obj1 == A("test1"))` line ?? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool operator ==( const A &other)
```

Use const reference, so a temporary object that is constructed in if statement can be used as parameter for operator==.

Comment: Thanks for quick response!! One thing I have observed is for this to work copy constructor argument should also be made const.

A(const A &c)

Comment: can you clarity the answer with example ??

Comment: @Graeme Perrow: It's not wrong. There *additionally* is a problem with `strcmp`, but without the change here in this answer it won't even compile.

Comment: @Graeme: It is the right answer. I quote the question: "What's wrong with if(obj1 == A("test1")) line ?". There is also the problem with strcmp, but it wasn't that the question...

Comment: The OP was expecting to see "This is true" as the output - the original code did not print it. I copied the original code to a file to verify this. (@sth: It compiled successfully.) I added the `const` lines and rebuilt it, and it __still printed nothing__, meaning that your answer did not fix the problem. If I made the strcmp change in Mike Weller's answer, the output was correct, with or without the `const` additions.

Comment: @Graeme: I think your compiler might be broken. If I fix the includes and compile the above, I get `error: no match for 'operator==' in 'obj1 == A(((char*)((const char*)"test1")))' \n note: candidates are: bool A::operator==(A&)`. Clearly gcc doesn't consider the const optional.

Comment: Oh, or could it be a C++0x thing?

Comment: I'm using MS Visual Studio 2005 on Windows. I tried it on a Linux box and there I _do_ see the compile error. So depending on the platform, this answer is not _wrong_, just incomplete. Mike's `strcmp` change is still required for correct behaviour.

Answer (score 34):

`strcmp` returns 0 when the strings are equal, so you want:

```
return strcmp(a, other.a) == 0;
```

You should also use a `const` reference like Cătălin Pitiș says in his answer, because then you can use temporary objects with the operator, and you should also make the method itself `const` (since it doesn't modify the object) as Andreas Brinck says in the comments below. So your method should be:

```
bool operator ==(const A &other) const
{
        return strcmp(a, other.a) == 0;
}
```

Comment: The functions should be const as well: `bool operator ==(const A &other) const`

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you want this in your operator:

```
strcmp(a, other.a) == 0
```

`strcmp` returns 0 when strings match, and a number indicating whether the comparison is greater or less than otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Your error is that you create an instant value and pass it as reference to the `operator==` method. But your error is in your operator definition that should be:

bool operator==(const A& other) const

the body being the same.

Comment: Adding the const stuff is definitely a good idea, _just_ adding the consts with "the body being the same" results in the same incorrect behaviour as the original program.

Comment: Correction: on some platforms, the const stuff is more than just a good idea, it's required. Mike's `strcmp` change is still required for correct behaviour.